# C#: SMO problems with dependencies / Multipe Create Table statements

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I'm trying to generate a SQL script from my existing database by using SMO.
This script will be used later to restore the database without data. 
For this, I set up a method that looks like this:

```
public void GenerateSQLScripts(string dbName)
    {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Server server = new Server(SqlServer);
        Database db = server.Databases[dbName];


        var scriptopt = new ScriptingOptions();
        scriptopt.TargetServerVersion = SqlServerVersion.Version105; // Windows 2008 R2
        scriptopt.AnsiPadding = true;
        scriptopt.WithDependencies = true;
        scriptopt.IncludeHeaders = true;
        scriptopt.SchemaQualify = true;
        scriptopt.ExtendedProperties = true;
        scriptopt.TargetDatabaseEngineType = DatabaseEngineType.Standalone;
        scriptopt.IncludeDatabaseContext = true;
        scriptopt.ScriptDrops = false;
        scriptopt.ScriptData = false;
        scriptopt.ScriptSchema = true;
        scriptopt.DriAllConstraints = true;
        scriptopt.DriForeignKeys = true;
        scriptopt.Indexes = true;
        scriptopt.DriPrimaryKey = true;
        scriptopt.DriUniqueKeys = true;
        scriptopt.DriChecks = true;
        scriptopt.AllowSystemObjects = false;
        scriptopt.AppendToFile = false;
        scriptopt.ScriptBatchTerminator = true;


        // script Tables
        foreach (Table t in db.Tables)
        {
            if (!t.IsSystemObject)
            {
                StringCollection sc = t.Script(scriptopt);
                foreach (string s in sc)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(s);
                }
            }

        }

        //Script Stored Procedures
        foreach (StoredProcedure sp in db.StoredProcedures)
        {
            if (!sp.IsSystemObject)
            {
                var sc = sp.Script(scriptopt);
                foreach (string s in sc)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(s);
                }
            } 

        }

        //Views
        foreach(View v in db.Views){
            if (!v.IsSystemObject)
            {
                StringCollection sc = v.Script(scriptopt);
                foreach (string s in sc)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(s);
                }
            }

        }
        File.WriteAllText(Path, sb.ToString());

    }
```

This method creates a SQL file that contains multiple `Create Table` statements for the same tables. This happens every time a table is referenced, regardless if it exists or not. 
I found a solution for this problem by turning WithDependencies off:

```
scriptopt.WithDependencies = false;
```

Now the script is much smaller since there are no additional statements. But since there is no order in my statements, some tables are referencing to other tables that do not exist at that time.
After some research I found the class [DependencyWalker](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.dependencywalker?view=sqlserver-2016).

I changed my code to use this class and to sort the order of statements in order to restore my database:

```
        UrnCollection ucol = new UrnCollection();
        foreach(Table t in db.Tables){
            ucol.Add(t.Urn);
        }

        DependencyWalker dw = new DependencyWalker(server);

        DependencyTree dtree = dw.DiscoverDependencies(ucol.ToArray(), DependencyType.Parents);

        DependencyCollection dcol = dw.WalkDependencies(dtree);

// ScriptingOptions

        Scripter scripter = new Scripter(server);
        foreach (Table t in db.Tables)
        {

            if (!t.IsSystemObject)
            {
                scripter.Options = scriptopt;
                scripter.Options.WithDependencies = false;
                IEnumerable<string> tscripts = scripter.EnumScriptWithList(dcol);
                foreach (string s in tscripts)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(s);
                }
            }
        }
```

The rest of the source code remains unaffected due to testing purposes.
Now I got the same error as before. My script is filled with multiple `Create Table` statements which leads to `Table already exists` errors even though the option is turned off .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, I've found a solution for my problem.
At first I changed the value of the `DriForeignKeys` to `false`.
This causes the Foreign Keys to be left out of the script for now. While the script for the tables is created, I extract their foreign keys by using a [ForeignKeyCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.foreignkeycollection?view=sqlserver-2016):

```
List<ForeignKeyCollection> fkcolList = new List<ForeignKeyCollection>();
foreach (Table t in db.Tables)
        {
            fkcolList.Add(t.ForeignKeys); // Extract the foreign keys
            if (!t.IsSystemObject)
            {
                StringCollection sc = t.Script(scriptopt);
                foreach (string s in sc)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(s);
                }
            }
        }
```

Now I can script the foreign keys separately and append it at the end of the script:

```
 foreach (ForeignKeyCollection fkcol in fkcolList) // Generate Relations
        {
            foreach (ForeignKey fk in fkcol)
            {
                StringCollection sc = fk.Script();
                foreach (string s in sc)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(s);
                }
            }
        }
        fkcolList.Clear();
```

This might won't be the best solution since there are three loops in a row but for me it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Smo is a barrel of laughs, isn't it? You're going to find that the dependency walker produced apparently redundant references to each table...because of multiple relationships...and cascading relationships.

Do yourself a favor and output the results of the dependency walker's tree (do your own walking)...so you can see that this is true. Here's what I did just to "see" what I'm getting. Note the indentation illustrates that tables are mentioned several times...and these are only being flattened into a "linear list" when you called WalkDependencies...which isn't doing you any good.

```
class Program
{
  static void Main( string[ ] args )
  {
    using ( var connection = new SqlConnection( "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=...;Integrated Security=True" ) )
    {
      connection.Open( );
      var serverConnection = new ServerConnection( connection );
      var server = new Server( serverConnection );
      var db = server.Databases[ "..." ];
      var objects = new UrnCollection( );
      foreach ( Table table in db.Tables )
      {
        objects.Add( table.Urn );
      }
      var dependency = new DependencyWalker( server );
      var tree = dependency.DiscoverDependencies( objects, DependencyType.Parents );
      Walk( tree.FirstChild );
    }
  }

  static void Walk( DependencyTreeNode node, int depth = 0 )
  {
    Print( node.Urn, depth );
    if ( node.HasChildNodes )
    {
      Walk( node.FirstChild, depth + 1 );
    }
    if ( node.NextSibling != null )
    {
      Walk( node.NextSibling, depth );
    }
  }

  static void Print( string message, int depth )
  {
    var space = string.Empty;
    for ( int i = 0; i < depth; i++ ) space += " ";
    Debug.WriteLine( string.Format( "{0}{1}", space, message ) );
  }
}
```

I ran the foregoing code on a small normalized database I have with a nominal set of foreign keys. It's these foreign keys that are resulting in multiple mentions of a given table.

Here's the partially-redacted output:

```
Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='AddressTypes' and @Schema='dbo']
Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='ApplicationComponents' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/UserDefinedFunction[@Name='GetApplicationElementExtension' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='ApplicationElements' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/UserDefinedFunction[@Name='GetApplicationElementName' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='ApplicationElements' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/UserDefinedFunction[@Name='GetArchitecture' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Architectures' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/UserDefinedFunction[@Name='GetArchitectureName' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Architectures' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/UserDefinedFunction[@Name='GetSetting' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Settings' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='ApplicationElements' and @Schema='dbo']
Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='ApplicationElements' and @Schema='dbo']
Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Architectures' and @Schema='dbo']
Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='DataFiles' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Sequence[@Name='FileSequence' and @Schema='dbo']
Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='DirectoryEntries' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Lists' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Sequence[@Name='ListSequence' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Names' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Sequence[@Name='NameSequence' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='SecurityIds' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Sequence[@Name='SecuritySequence' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Sequence[@Name='DirectoryEntrySequence' and @Schema='dbo']
Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Images' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Snapshots' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Machines' and @Schema='dbo']
   Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Architectures' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Sequence[@Name='SnapshotSequence' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Progress' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Progress' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Architectures' and @Schema='dbo']
Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='KeyTypes' and @Schema='dbo']
Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='ListItems' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Streams' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='DataFiles' and @Schema='dbo']
   Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Sequence[@Name='FileSequence' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Lists' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Sequence[@Name='ListSequence' and @Schema='dbo']
Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Lists' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Sequence[@Name='ListSequence' and @Schema='dbo']
Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='MachineAddresses' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Machines' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Architectures' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='AddressTypes' and @Schema='dbo']
Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='MachineKeys' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Machines' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Architectures' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Sequence[@Name='MachineKeySequence' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='KeyTypes' and @Schema='dbo']
Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Machines' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Architectures' and @Schema='dbo']
Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Names' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Sequence[@Name='NameSequence' and @Schema='dbo']
Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Progress' and @Schema='dbo']
Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='SecurityIds' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Sequence[@Name='SecuritySequence' and @Schema='dbo']
Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Settings' and @Schema='dbo']
Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='SnapshotDirectoryEntries' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Snapshots' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Machines' and @Schema='dbo']
   Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Architectures' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Sequence[@Name='SnapshotSequence' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Progress' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='DirectoryEntries' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Lists' and @Schema='dbo']
   Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Sequence[@Name='ListSequence' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Names' and @Schema='dbo']
   Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Sequence[@Name='NameSequence' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='SecurityIds' and @Schema='dbo']
   Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Sequence[@Name='SecuritySequence' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Sequence[@Name='DirectoryEntrySequence' and @Schema='dbo']
Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Snapshots' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Machines' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Architectures' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Sequence[@Name='SnapshotSequence' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Progress' and @Schema='dbo']
Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='Streams' and @Schema='dbo']
 Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Table[@Name='DataFiles' and @Schema='dbo']
  Server[@Name='...']/Database[@Name='...']/Sequence[@Name='FileSequence' and @Schema='dbo']
```

A quick scan reveals that some tables are referenced six or seven times.

It's gonna get worse before it gets better. What you're ultimately going to have to do is ferret out independent things...things that can be scripted first. These things have no dependencies. Then, put those independent items in a list and run the dependency walker over and over, adding things to your list...where items are dependent only on items you've already added. Thus, you'll have s scriptable order.

Note that a database-in-place can be technically still end up being irresolvable this way. Table a can have a ref to table b, which has a ref to table a. It's perfectly legal (even if undesirable).

What I prefer to do is to use Visual Studio to do the hard work:

1. Add SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017)
2. Create a Database project.
3. Import your existing database.
4. Build+Publish menu to generate a script.

It can do magic things...like create objects and then modify them later to deal with the a->b->a type things. You can also publish to an existing database, and it will carefully produce a script that makes only the changes. It's awesome.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I was aware that the tree contains all the redundant information about the dependencies. Thats why I turned the option "WithDependencies" off, hoping that it would just scripting the tables without dependencies. I've read about SQL SDT before but it doesn't seem like a fitting solution for me since my tool has other tasks besides the scripting. Is there a way to use SDT programmatically?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of... I think you can ultimately have success with SMO...it just takes a lot of playing with to see what you're really getting. Perhaps I'm not seeing the whole picture...but from your last code it looks like you're foreach-ing through all the tables...and then at each table, you're scripting absolutely everything in the dcol...which is itself...the redundant "everything". Sorry if I'm missing the point.

Comment: You're absolutely right, that's what I'm trying to do. I thought I could use the class ScriptingOptions to filter the redundant information. It worked on the first attempt without the DependencyWalker. But it seems that the Scripter class ignores the scripting options.

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to iterate through anything manually. Just configure the scripter to include the types you want (tables, stored procs, owner, even data) and run it and it will handle dependencies (at least it did for me generating a DataOnly script):

```
var server = new Server(@".\SQLExpress");
var database = server.Databases["mydb"];
var scripter = new Scripter(server);
//scripter.Options.WithDependencies = true; //didn't even need this option
scripter.Options.ScriptData = true;
scripter.Options.ScriptSchema = false;

var tables = database.Tables.Cast<Table>().Where(t => !t.IsSystemObject).ToList();
var scripts = scripter.EnumScriptWithList(tables.Select(t => t.Urn).ToArray());

return string.Join("\n", scripts.Select(s => s));
```